# How can I rsync all my web nodes off of a master?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, load-balancing, rsync

I am trying to sync a bunch of domains (a.com, b.com, and c.com) on a bunch of load balanced web nodes (w1, w2, w3).

I plan to build to node 1 (w1) and then rsync to the others with something like this:

```
rsync -arv /var/www/vhosts/a.com/ root@w1:/var/www/vhosts/a.com/
```

With a dynamic script like (assume I'm on w1 already) :

```
#!/bin/bash

DOMAINS="a.com b.com c.com"
NODES="w2 w3"

for DOMAIN in $DOMAINS; do
        for NODE in $NODES; do
                COMMAND="rsync -arv --exclude 'logs' --exclude '.git' /var/www/vhosts/$DOMAIN/ root@$NODE:/var/www/vhosts/$DOMAIN/"
                echo "$COMMAND"
                "$COMMAND"
        done
done
```

The first, manual, `rsync` works just fine.  But for some reason my batch rsync script is breaking.

Anyone care to help debug for me?  Thanks.

Comment: Run it with `-x` (`sh -x yourscript`) and see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Forget it.  It was an issue with my node alias names.  My bad.  I'll revert the question and give you credit for the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some excessive quoting going on there.  Change this line:

```
"$COMMAND"
```

To this:

```
$COMMAND
```

When you put quotes around the whole thing, the shell interprets it as a single "token".  Here's a simple example:

```
$ COMMAND="echo hello"
$ "$COMMAND"
bash: echo: command not found...
$ $COMMAND
hello
```